# Game is freezing after playing for a while

Tags: games, freeze

I just type this command to run the exe file of game

*Wine hitman2*

Then  playing Hitman 2 silent Assassin for a minutes it's just freeze and then show a message in screen that wine is not responding

Comment: Check if you maybe run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your wine config to backup

`mv ~/.wine ~/.wine.backup`

then relauch wine using (it will automatically create a new wine config)

`wine` (or `winecfg`, etc.)